# Valid Characters Between HTML Attributes

Tags: javascript, html

This might be a silly thing to do; but I'm trying to allow 'some' HTML on a website (okay, it's probably a bad idea).  But, for the sake of argument...

Is there ANY non-white space character you can place between an attribute and the '='s sign and still have a modern browser be able to interpret the attribute.

In other words; if the user enters:

```
<img src="pic1.jpg" width=50 height=50 onClick='alert("Hi");'>
```

Is there any character(s) that can appear after 'onClick' but before the '=' sign and still have it execute the javascript alert message in any of the big name browsers, besides spaces and enters?

As an example - I tried inserting '&nbsp' (and it fails)...

But is there another clever way of interjecting something I might miss.

Comment: Sounds like a huge permutation would be necessary to know, since you say `render correctly`.

Comment: @Rob Are you parsing HTML with a parser, or are you using a regex or other home brewed solution?

Comment: @Ziggy - Truthfully, it's more in the hypothetical stage at this point.  I haven't implemented anything.  I was trying to think of a relatively easy way to prevent Javascript while still allowing many HTML tags.

Comment: @Josh - I've tried to clarify the question to make it more specific.  Thanks

Comment: I think this is helpful: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: @BalusC - Wow - that link is both scary and helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of looking; I've been unable to find anything that can appear between the 'attribute = value' that isn't white space.

Comment: I think you missed a negation (e.g. "not") somewhere in the sentence?